# Finding the intersect of two lists (SML / NJ)

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj, fold

I have an iterative foldr function:

```
fun iterFold f v [] = v
 |   iterFold f v (x::xs) = iterFold f (f(v,x)) xs;
```

And a function that takes in a predicate and a list. The function compares the list to the predicate and returns true if there is a single occurrence.

```
fun exist3 p M = foldr( fn(x,y) => y orelse (p x)) false M
```

Using these two functions, I need to write a one-line function that returns the intersection of two lists. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`I have an iterative foldr function`.

It is not `foldr`, but `foldl`. The difference is that `foldr` goes from last element of a list to first and `foldl` goes from first element of a list to last.

They way to write the function:

```
fun intersect ls1 ls2 = iterFold (fn (is,l1) =>
                                    if exist3 (fn (l2) => l1 = l2) ls2
                                    then l1::is
                                    else is)
                                 [] ls1
```

(you can format it as one-liner, but I think you meant it just should call one function)

The idea is to go through `ls1` and add  to result elements that also in `ls2`. Since we are going from first element to last, elements in resulting list will appear in order opposite to their order in `ls1`.

```
- intersect [1,2,3] [1,2,3];
val it = [3,2,1] : int list
- intersect [2,4,5] [1,2,3,5];
val it = [5,2] : int list
```

Comment: Recursive functions of the form above (i.e., where there is only one recursive call and that's a tail call) are sometimes called iterative, because they correspond exactly to a loop.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg Could you please point me to any authoritative sources that do that? Or, is that something that people do for convenience colloquially, just not to say something like "recursive function that traverses a list"?

Comment: One pointer I could find off-hand are these lecture notes by McCarthy, who speaks of recursion equations in iterative form: http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/towards/node9.html From the perspective of lambda calculus, a loop is just syntactic sugar for a recursive function in that form. This is literally true in SML: the only looping construct `while e1 do e2` expands into `let fun f() = if e1 then (e2; f()) else () in f() end` per the language spec. So a purely syntactic interpretation of the word "iterative" is less useful than one might think.

Comment: @zaquest SICP does it: http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.1

Comment: @mazayus SICP tells us kind of opposite thing: not to confuse the notion of recursive process and recursive procedure; thus, I assume we should not confuse the notion of iterative process and iterative procedure.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg, you are apparently right that tail-recursive functions are sometimes called iterative (though, I think it just adds confusion and it'd be better to clearly separate procedures and processes they create, as in SICP). Anyway this kind of things more suits cs.stackexchage.com, so I updated my answer.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg Not that I think McCarthy was confusing in the link you posted. He provided good context and clearly stated that function is recursive while also calling it non-iterative.